# Filter list using a formula (without VBA)

Tags: excel

To be clear, this question is not about the Excel terms "filter" or "autofilter".  I have a sheet of values that I don't want to alter in any way (sheet1).  I have another sheet (sheet2) that I want to create that contains a subset of the rows in sheet1.  Is there a way to do this using a formula without leaving any blank rows?

Example below:

```
   A      | B
 --------------------
1| Person | Age
2| Bob    | 25
3| Mary   | 10
4| Sue    | 15
5| Bill   | 20
6| Sam    | 35
SHEET1 ("People")

   A      | B
 --------------------
1| Person | Age
2| Bob    | 25
3| Bill   | 20
4| Sam    | 35
SHEET2 ("Adults")
```

I want to enter a formula in Sheet2 that will capture rows in Sheet1 (similar to how a filter would work).  This is trivial with blank rows, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this without blank rows.

Comment: PowerQuery is a great tool for this, but you can also just use a humble PivotTable with a Values Filter to only show age > 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data query to the same Workbook, referencing the sheet with all data.

1. Ribbon -> get Data -> From File -> From Workbook
2. Select the same file, then the "People" sheet in the tree view.

[image]

3. Apply the appropriate filter to the resulting query table, using the filtering method of your choice. One option is to filter in the data query directly -

   ```
   let
       Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\jdphe\OneDrive\Documents\Book1.xlsx"), null, true),
       Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
       #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
       #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Person", type text}, {"Age", Int64.Type}}),
       #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Age] >= 18)
   in
       #"Filtered Rows"
   ```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because it led me in the right direction.  I actually ended up using Google sheets and used this formula: QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"SELECT A,B WHERE B>=18") which gave me exactly what I was looking for.